# Flutter text overflow with trailing container in Row widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In below code I'm getting Text Overflow, but what I need is, if text is to large it should fade in before the view text.

```
ExpansionTile(
    leading: Wrap(
      spacing: DynamicSize.Azwidth(30),
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.menu_rounded,
          color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
        ),
        SvgPicture.asset('images/fire.svg'),
      ],
    ),
    title: Text(
      'Foam Rolling',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: DynamicSize.Azheight(16),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontFamily: 'DMSans',
        color: Color(0xFF193669),
      ),
    ),
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: DynamicSize.Azwidth(97), right: DynamicSize.Azwidth(24)),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset('images/bullet.svg'),
                  SizedBox(width: DynamicSize.Azwidth(16)),
                  Text(
                    'Foam Rolling Front Hip !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    softWrap: false,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('View'),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                    size: DynamicSize.Azheight(13),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
```

The Output of above code is :

[image]

Their is a container widget after exclamation in the text. I even tried wrapping the text widget that overflows with Expanded widget as well as Flexible widget. But the text as well as the bullet point before the text gets invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap inner row with `Row` and `Text` with `Flexible` widget.

```dart
children: [
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'Foam Rolling Front Hip !!!!!!!!!sdssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!',
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                maxLines: 1,
                softWrap: true,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```